# Sprite Wont Spawn unless Score is 0 Xcode Swift Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a working Space Shooter game. Basic setup. Player controls a ship moving left and right and bullets automatically Spawn. I want to add "Bosses" after you reach a certain score.

To play around with it, I had it to if Score == 5, make the sprite appear and move

It wasnt working so I put the Score to 0 and it spawns and moves to its position.

I am stuck on my it isnt working. My guess was that the Boss Sprite and EnemyShips were colliding to much when they spawned and didnt let the Boss Sprite Spawn.

The Boss sprite is named tj.JPG

So i added a CollisonBitMask and set it to 0 but that didnt work either.

Is it an issue with the EnemyTimer? I even set the repeat = false just to test it and set the score == 1 and it didnt have any affect either.

Any help would be appreciated. I would love to learn how to do add Bosses correctly after you reach a desired Score.

Here is my GameScene

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

struct PhysicsCatagory {
    static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1 //000000000000000000000000000001
    static let Bullet : UInt32 = 2 //00000000000000000000000000010
    static let Player : UInt32 = 3 //00000000000000000000000000100
    static let tj: UInt32  = 4
}



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var Highscore = Int()
    var Score = Int()

    var Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player.png")
    var ScoreLbl = UILabel()





    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if (HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil){

            Highscore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger
        }
        else {

            Highscore = 0
        }


        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)

        self.addChild(SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "SparkParticle")!)


        Player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 5)
        Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Player.size)
        Player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
        Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
        Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false


        var Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        var EnemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnEnemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
// --------------------------        
        if Score == 1 {
            let TJ = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tj.JPG")

            TJ.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: TJ.size)
            TJ.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.tj
            TJ.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
            TJ.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            TJ.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            // TJ.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


            TJ.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height + 30)
            let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height / 2, duration: 2.0)

            TJ.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action]))
            self.addChild(TJ)
        }
        // ------------------



        self.addChild(Player)

        ScoreLbl.text  = "\(Score)"
        ScoreLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        ScoreLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0.3)
        ScoreLbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view?.addSubview(ScoreLbl)

    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {



        let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

        if (((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet)) ||
            ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy))){

                CollisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }
        else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Player) ||
            (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy)){

                CollisionWithPerson(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Person: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }

    }

    func CollisionWithBullet(Enemy: SKSpriteNode, Bullet:SKSpriteNode){
        Enemy.removeFromParent()
        Bullet.removeFromParent()
        Score++


        ScoreLbl.text = "\(Score)"
        print(Score)
    }



    func CollisionWithPerson(Enemy:SKSpriteNode, Person: SKSpriteNode){
        let ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
        ScoreDefault.synchronize()


        if (Score > Highscore){

            let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            HighscoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Highscore")

        }

        Enemy.removeFromParent()
        Person.removeFromParent()
        self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())
        ScoreLbl.removeFromSuperview()



    }



    func SpawnBullets(){
        let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "papercup.png")
        Bullet.zPosition = -5

        Bullet.position = CGPointMake(Player.position.x, Player.position.y)

        let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.8)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        Bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

        Bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Bullet.size)
        Bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
        Bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
        Bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.addChild(Bullet)
    }

    func SpawnEnemies(){



        let Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dispenser.png")
        let MinValue = self.size.width / 8
        let MaxValue = self.size.width - 150
        let SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
        Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
        Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Enemy.size)
        Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Enemy
        Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
        Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true



        let action = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 2.0)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        Enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

        self.addChild(Enemy)

     //   if Score == 5
      //  {
      //      Enemy.removeFromParent()
      //  }


    }










    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            Player.position.x = location.x




        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            Player.position.x = location.x




        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

here is where the issue is

```
if Score == 1 {
            let TJ = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tj.JPG")

            TJ.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: TJ.size)
            TJ.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.tj
            TJ.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bullet
            TJ.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            TJ.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            // TJ.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


            TJ.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height + 30)
            let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height / 2, duration: 2.0)

            TJ.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action]))
            self.addChild(TJ)
        }
```

Comment: I admit that I have not read your code snippet. Still, would it be possible to provide a minimal example of code producing the problem? It seems like you want someone to find a logical flaw and fix your code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am just looking for the right step forward. The game works fine but adding another sprite to appear after a certain score is being more difficult than it should be.

Comment: It is just a lot of code for something probably very simple.

Comment: @bellwright You are running that code inside `didMoveToView` and that method is called once, immediately after the scene (self) has been presented by the view. That code is executed only once. You need something like that inside of a didBeginContact (or where ever you update your score variable).

Comment: @WhirlWind . that makes so much sense now. Thank you!!

Comment: Also note that you should follow naming conventions.. It is variableName, longVariableName, ClassName, methodName etc...

Comment: As Whirlwind said, I guess the problem is that you're not writing the code on the correct place. For example, I would write it where the score is increased so you check if it has raised the desired value. Regarding the naming convention, take a look to the "camelBack (or camel-back) notation" on this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: didMoveToView() is to prepare the view. You might want to add that code in your update() function.